# Select keys with boolean value true in PostgreSQL json query

Tags: json, postgresql, boolean, where-clause

In my **PostgreSQL** **11.6** table I have a **json** field `app_settings` with data on the following format:

```
{
   "my_app": {
      "features": {
         "very_good_feature": true,
         "awesome_feature": false,
         "even_better_feature": true
      }
   }
}
```

I want to create a query that selects a list of feature names where the feature has the value `true`. So in the example above, I would like the result of the query simply to be 2 rows like this:

1. very_good_feature
2. even_better_feature

I can successfully select ALL the keys with the following query:

```
select
    json_object_keys(app_settings ->'my_app' -> 'features') as k
from
    my_table;
```

*How can I write the `where` clause to only list the ones with `true` as value?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with `json_each_text`:

```
select j.* from my_table
join lateral json_each_text(app_settings->'my_app'->'features') j(k, v) on true
where
j.v = 'true'
```

Comment: Great! That worked. I am curious, what kind of performance can I expect from this query? Would I be better off by rearranging my data in a way that allows for faster query?

Comment: Nice to help! If in rearrange you mean, save data in general table/sql-ish way (instead of json), then of course operate with it, would be more performant